# Eclipse does not include C++ libraries correctly in Kubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, ubuntu

I'm having a problem with C++11 libraries. I'm using Eclipse in Kubuntu with latest gcc and g++ compilers. I'm using C++ 4.7.2 library.

Eclipse finds all the libraries just fine, but still there are problems. For example:

```
#include <random>
typedef std::mt19937 myRandom;
```

This code results an error: "Type 'std::mt19937' could not be resolved". It seems that not all functionality in random was not included. Same problem exists for cout and cin in iostream. What could be wrong?

-Juho L

Comment: You need to tell Eclipse to tel gcc to use C++11, which is not the default. The compiler option is `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: I already used a -std=gnu++11 tag. I tried if -std=c++0x made any difference, but no. There are some functions in the std::, like std::abs(x), so it seems that there is only a part of C++ library there and the includes do not have any effect.

Comment: Udate: I managed to get cin and cout to work. I just went to the project properties-C/C++ Build-Discovery Options and changed the discovery to automate. Tried again without result. Then disabled it again and then iostream was recognised. No dice with the random, though.