# How to resolve C++ error with <random> library in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I am using the  library in Eclipse with gcc 4.8.0; however, testing the following code

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <random>  
int main()  
{  
    int randomSeed = 1234;  
    std::mt19937 gen(randomSeed);  
    return 0;  
}
```

results in the error "Type 'std::mt19937' could not be resolved"

I have used the -std=c++11 and -std=c++0x flags with no success as was suggested in this previous post: [Eclipse does not include C++ libraries correctly in Kubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585206/eclipse-does-not-include-c-libraries-correctly-in-kubuntu)

-reptar

Comment: Does the code not compile or is it just the editor showing red lines under `std::mt19937`?

Comment: It was the editor. I found a fix where I needed to go to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols -> add, then add__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ with no value defined and __cplusplus with 201103L as the value.